filter of Filter in javascript array
I have an array that I'm trying to filter:


const elements = ['apple'];

const objects = [
  { id: 1, fruit:[{"name": "apple" },{"name": "banana" }]},
  { id: 2, fruit:[{"name": "apple" },{"name": "orange" }]},
  { id: 3, fruit:[{"name": "orange" },{"name": "banana" }]},
  { id: 4, fruit:[{"name": "orange" },{"name": "banana" }]}
];

const results = objects.filter(obj => obj.fruit.filter( ele => elements.includes(ele.name)));
console.log(results);



I am getting the output as below but this not what I am expecting:
{id: 1, fruit:[{"name": "apple" },{"name": "banana" }]
{id: 2, fruit:[{"name": "apple" },{"name": "banana" }]

I want the output as below:
{ id: 1, fruit:[{"name": "apple" }]}
{ id: 2, fruit:[{"name": "apple" }]}


The "output" you showed is quite different from the one from "Run code snippet", though

You could filter fruit and if it has elements take the outer object as result.


const
    elements = ['apple'],
    objects = [{ id: 1, fruit: [{ name: "apple" }, { name: "banana" }] }, { id: 2, fruit: [{ name: "apple" }, { name: "orange" }] }, { id: 3, fruit: [{ name: "orange" }, { name: "banana" }] }, { id: 4, fruit: [{ name: "orange" }, { name: "banana" }] }],
    results = objects.reduce((r, o) => {
        const fruit = o.fruit.filter(({ name }) => elements.includes(name));
        if (fruit.length) r.push({ ...o, fruit });
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(results);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




If it is admissible that the objects of the input array can be changed, then your "filter of filter" approach can be made to work like this:


const elements = ['apple'];

const objects = [
  { id: 1, fruit:[{"name": "apple" },{"name": "banana" }]},
  { id: 2, fruit:[{"name": "apple" },{"name": "orange" }]},
  { id: 3, fruit:[{"name": "orange" },{"name": "banana" }]},
  { id: 4, fruit:[{"name": "orange" },{"name": "banana" }]}
];

const results = objects.filter(obj => (obj.fruit=obj.fruit.filter( ele => elements.includes(ele.name)),obj.fruit.length));
console.log(results);



The inner .filter() will now reduce the original elements of the fruit array to the ones contained in elements. And only if there has been at least one match (obj.fruit.length) the outer. .filter() condition is met.
